# Ring with infinitely many totally ordered prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I was looking for a specific ring with infinitely many prime ideals such that they are totally ordered by inclusion.
A valuation ring with rank $\mathbb{N} \cup \infty$ should work, or something like that, but I don't know any.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Probably the meaning is that the set of prime ideals is totally ordered by inclusion.

Comment: @egreg that makes perfect sense, thanks for helping me out there.

Comment: Do you mean that there is some set of prime ideals which is totally ordered by inclusion or that the collection of all prime ideals needs to be totally ordered by inclusion? Also, $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty \}$ isn't a group under addition.

Comment: Thanks, edited, I mean all primes.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But there are other prime ideals.

Comment: @egreg I see. I misread the question as asking for a ring that has an infinite chain of prime ideals as opposed to a ring such that all the prime ideals are linearly ordered.